# Spring Data JPA Many to Many Service Repository Problem

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to add ManyToMany entity to my application. I created entity but cannot implement it.

**Actor class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "actor")
public class Actor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "actor_name")
    private String actorName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Movie> movie = new HashSet<Movie>();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getActorName() { return actorName; }

    public void setActorName(String actorName) {
        this.actorName = actorName;
    }

    public Set<Movie> getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }

    public void setMovie(Set<Movie> movie) {
       this.movie = movie;
    }
}
```

In **movie class** I have

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "movie_actor",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "actor_id")}
    )
    Set<Actor> actor = new HashSet<Actor>();

........................

 public Set<Actor> getActor () {
        return actor;
    }

    public void setActor(Set<Actor> actor){
        this.actor = actor;
    }
```

I created my entity just like this but in **MovieService**;

```
Actor actor = ActorRepository.findByActorName(movie.getActor().getActorName());
        movie.setActor(actor);
```

This part gives me error. movie.getActor().getActorName() method cannot find. Where do I need to look? In IDE it also says method getActorName and setActorName is never used. I am also adding my ActorRepository and ActorService to closer look to the problem.

**ActorRepository**

```
public interface ActorRepository extends JpaRepository<Actor, Integer> {

    Set<Actor> findByActorName(String actorName);
}
```

**ActorService**

```
@Service
public class ActorService {

    private ActorRepository actorRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ActorService(ActorRepository actorRepository) {
        this.actorRepository = actorRepository;
    }

    public List<Actor> getAllActor() {
        return actorRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

After adding ManyToMany I was using is as OneToMany entity. Services is works for OneToMany. How can I use them for ManyToMany? I need to add multiple actors to my movies. I couldn't find MVC projects for ManyToMany implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're invoking `movie.getActor().getActorName()` which basically does a `getActorName()` on a `Set<Actor>` object.

You're basically treating the relation as a `ManyToOne` instead of a `OneToMany`

You could use the following to fetch the first `Actor` of the `Set`

```
ActorRepository.findByActorName(movie.getActors().iterator().next().getActorName());
```

But then of course, you don't have all your `Actor`'s names

What you could do is the following

```
public interface ActorRepository extends JpaRepository<Actor, Integer> {

    Set<Actor> findByActorNameIn(List<String> actorName);
}
```

And invoke it that way

```
ActorRepository.findByActorNameIn(
    movie.getActors()
         .stream()
         .map(Actor::getName)
         .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

Comment: That is really makes sense but I still gives me error.  `/home/fatih/Desktop/spring-boot-product-system/src/main/java/com/fatih/movie/service/MovieService.java:[41,56] incompatible types: java.util.Set<com.fatih.movie.model.Actor> cannot be converted to com.fatih.movie.model.Actor
[ERROR] /home/fatih/Desktop/spring-boot-product-system/src/main/java/com/fatih/movie/service/MovieService.java:[42,24] incompatible types: com.fatih.movie.model.Actor cannot be converted to java.util.Set<com.fatih.movie.model.Actor> `

Comment: Post your code for `MovieService`, you basically just have to adapt it there too